# Why this error come: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp

I'm trying to connect to the API Mailchimp but I have this error that come when I launch the `app.js`.

```
import mailchimp from "@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing";

mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  server: "server",
});

async function run() {
  const response = await mailchimp.ping.get();
  console.log(response);
}

run();
```

**And here is the complete error:**

```
(node:27226) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:27226) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27226) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

`ECONNREFUSED` means that your OS isn't able to setup a TCP connection. There's no service listening on `0.0.0.0:443`, which is your own computer. Are you sure that `0.0.0.0` is the host you need to connect to?

Either you need to start the required service on your computer or you need to use the correct IP address (whatever that may be).

Comment: Alright, but I actualy only need the apiKey and the server in the mailchimp.setconfig and the errror still occur.

Comment: The 0.0.0.0 is a fake ip adress, I don't want to put the real one

Comment: I understand, can you try to access the https endpoint directly to see if you can setup the connection? It could also be a firewall issue since you're getting a TCP failure instead of an error or something

Comment: Ok, yes I can access it

Comment: "The 0.0.0.0 is a fake ip adress, I don't want to put the real one" << it should be MailChimp's IP anyway, not yours... so it shouldn't be a problem to post it here, it would in fact help to understand what's happening.

Comment: And please remember to edit those details into your post.

Comment: In my experience, Nodejs isn't so specific with what's actually causing an error.  I received this ECONNREFUSED error message in the context of Firebase Cloud Messaging, trying to send a message.  After reading Stack I thought it meant I should setup a proxy situation, but that made no difference bc my connection wasn't really the problem.  It was an error in the object I drafted to send which needed editing - after editing the error went away and everything was fine.  Bear this in mind: consider how one wrong thing can make another appear to be wrong.